# Converting SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a specific SQL query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblIm WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP  20  Id FROM tblIm)
```

I just tried this:

```
var results = from myRow in Ds.AsEnumerable().Take(minRecords)
              where myRow.Field<int>("Trail_Id") > 1 
              && myRow.Field<int>("Id") <= 20
select myRow;
```

but it's not working as i want. So how do I convert it to a LINQ statement that works like the SQL statement?

Any suggestions?

Thank you all But I got Solution 
finally :

```
var testresult = from c in  Ds.AsEnumerable().Take(20) 
                         where !(from o in Ds.AsEnumerable().Take(intSkip)    
                         select o)    
                        .Contains(c)    
                        select c;
```

Comment: I would just put it in a sproc and call the sproc to be honest :)

Comment: I'm would guess `tblIm.Id` is the clustered index for your table, however you should still include `ORDER BY tblIm.Id` on both `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 5):

I think that would be something like

```
tblIm.Skip(20).Take(20)
```

Comment: This Is the Solution I got Finally 

var testresult = from c in  Ds.AsEnumerable().Take(20) 
                             where !(from o in Ds.AsEnumerable().Take(intSkip)    
                             select o)    
                            .Contains(c)    
                            select c;